# Issue returning a Hashmap from a TestNg DataProvider

Tags: java, testng

I am pretty new to Java and TestNg.  I have created the below DataProvider to return a hashmap to my test method but it seems to be failing and I can't work out where the issue is.  I am reading an excel file into a hashmap and storing this in the list.  I then want to return the hashmap in the object.

Any advice appreciated

```
@DataProvider(name = "DataProvider")
public Object[][] getTestData() throws Exception {
    LogUtil.error("in provider");
    ExcelUtils.setExcelFile("C://testData.xlsx", "Sheet1");

    int rowsUsed = ExcelUtils.getRowUsed();
    int colsUsed = ExcelUtils.getColumns();

    List<HashMap<String, String>> arrayMapList = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;


    for (int i = 0; i < rowsUsed; i++) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < colsUsed; j++) {
            map.put(ExcelUtils.getCellData(0, j), ExcelUtils.getCellData(i +1, j));
        }

        arrayMapList.add(map);
    }

    Object[][] obj = new Object[rowsUsed][1];

    for (int i = 0; i <arrayMapList.size(); i++) {
        obj[i][0] = arrayMapList.get(i);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: I have changed the method to static and it works now.

Comment: you might want to post your answer and then accept it as well, so that the question gets closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saying that adding static property fixed your issue it means that you tried to use data provider from external class. For that case data provider method have to be static. If your test method and data provider are both in the same class static property could be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the method to static fixed the issue.  As answered by RocketRaccoon I had to change it to static because the data provider was in a different class to the tests.